# Spark DataFrame: find and set the main root for child

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I have the following Apache Spark Dataframe:

> *Parent* - *Child* 
>   **A1**     -   **A10** 
>   **A1**     -   **A2** 
>   **A2**     -   **A3** 
>   **A3**     -   **A4** 
>   **A5**     -   **A7** 
>   **A7**     -   **A6** 
>   **A8**     -   **A9**

This DataFrame displays a connection between parent and child. Logically it looks like this one: 
[image]

The main goal is setting the main root for each child. That's mean we should have the follwoing dataframe:

> *Parent* - *Child* 
>   **A1**     -   **A10** 
>   **A1**     -   **A2** 
>   **A1**     -   **A3** 
>   **A1**     -   **A4** 
>   **A5**     -   **A7** 
>   **A5**     -   **A6** 
>   **A8**     -   **A9**

- *Everything should implement using Apache Spark.*
- *The number of nodes is unlimited. That's mean algorithms should work regardless of the number of nodes*

Comment: Can you give sample response what are you looking ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the below approach I believe you can achieve it

```
val input_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("A1", "A10"), ("A1", "A2"), ("A2", "A3"), ("A3", "A4"), ("A5", "A7"), ("A7", "A6"), ("A8", "A9"), ("A4", "A11"), ("A11", "A12"), ("A6", "A13")))
val input_df = input_rdd.toDF("Parent", "Child")
input_df.createOrReplaceTempView("TABLE1")
input_df.show()
```

Input

```
+------+-----+
|Parent|Child|
+------+-----+
|    A1|  A10|
|    A1|   A2|
|    A2|   A3|
|    A3|   A4|
|    A5|   A7|
|    A7|   A6|
|    A8|   A9|
|    A4|  A11|
|   A11|  A12|
|    A6|  A13|
+------+-----+
```

```
# # linkchild function to get the root    
      def linkchild(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("TEMP")
    val link_child_df = spark.sql("""select distinct a.parent, b.child from TEMP a inner join TEMP b on a.parent = b.parent or a.child = b.parent""")
    link_child_df
    }
# # findroot function to validate and generate output
    def findroot(rdf: DataFrame) {
      val link_child_df = linkchild(rdf)
      link_child_df.createOrReplaceTempView("TEMP1")
      val cnt = spark.sql("""select * from table1 where child not in (select  child from (select * from (select distinct a.parent, b.child from TEMP1 a   inner join TEMP1 b on a.parent = b.parent or a.child = b.parent
    where a.parent not in(select distinct child from                                                                               TABLE1))))""").count()
      if (cnt == 0) {
        spark.sql("""select * from (select distinct a.parent, b.child from   TEMP1 a inner join TEMP1 b on a.parent = b.parent or a.child = b.parent
    where a.parent not in(select distinct child from TABLE1)) order by parent, child""").show
      } else {
        findroot(link_child_df)
      }
    }
# # Calling findroot function for the first time with input_df which in turn calls linkchild function till it reaches target
    findroot(input_df)
```

Output

```
+------+-----+
|parent|child|
+------+-----+
|    A1|  A10|
|    A1|  A11|
|    A1|  A12|
|    A1|  A14|
|    A1|  A15|
|    A1|  A16|
|    A1|  A17|
|    A1|  A18|
|    A1|   A2|
|    A1|   A3|
|    A1|   A4|
|    A5|  A13|
|    A5|   A6|
|    A5|   A7|
|    A8|   A9|
+------+-----+
```

Comment: `A12` is not exists in final result for this input `val input_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("A1", "A10"), ("A1", "A2"), ("A2", "A3"), ("A3", "A4"), ("A5", "A7"), ("A7", "A6"), ("A8", "A9"), ("A4", "A11"), ("A11", "A12"), ("A6", "A13")))`

Comment: A12 is not available because A12 parent is child of A4 & A4 is child of A3 and A3 is child of A2 and A2 is child of A1.. as per your first example it is like your are considering only A1 in that group. That is the reason we have NOT IN in the final Query which eliminated A12 in the final result. If you want to see A12 in final result remove the NOT IN in the query you will get it.

Comment: my expectation that algorithms will detect the main root for each child. In this case, the algorithm also has to show A1 - A12 in the final result. If I remove NOT IN in the query, it's not working as I expect

Comment: Just made an update to my answer, please validate it with your scenarios.

Comment: in this output, you have `A11 - A12`. It's not correct because the main parent for A11 is A1, therefore A1 is also main parent for A12. The output has to have `A1 - A12`.

Comment: I just realized and corrected it, please check now.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I think we have some misunderstandings. Your algorithms work the only with the finite number of nodes like from A1 - A12. I try to find a solution for the common cases (independently of the number of nodes). I have updated the description. 
In fact, I have a lot of nodes (it can be more than 10000) and try to find common solution.

Comment: I just tried with this input - input_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("A1", "A10"), ("A1", "A2"), ("A2", "A3"), ("A3", "A4"), ("A5", "A7"), ("A7", "A6"), ("A8", "A9"), ("A4", "A11"), ("A11", "A12"), ("A6", "A13"),("A12", "A14"),("A14", "A15"),("A15", "A16"),("A16", "A17"))) and it seems to working fine for me.. is this input as what your are expecting.

Comment: the number of nodes can be more than 10000. The algorithm doesn't have to depend on the number of nodes. It should be a common solution. For example, If I add in your input 100 nodes `(... ("A17", "A18"),("A18", "A19"),("A19", "A20")....("A99", "A100") )`, will it work?

Comment: I just updated my answer, now i can say that it works for any number of nodes.. please check!