# Find Top Parent in Scala Data Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a requirement for finding top most parent id for some data in spark data  frame.

I do have two columns as shown below with object id and parent object id.

[image]

object id **123** is having parent obj id as **456** and also it is an object id with parent id as **789** ...and so on.

The requirement is to find the topmost parent for each object id.

The expected output is as shown below.

[image]

I tried by creating temp table and rewriting the table with a while loop. but it seems like that is not working properly.

Is there any way to achieve this requirement? Any leads appreciated!

Tried with the solution provided in the below question, but it keeps on executing for a long time, seems like somewhere it is in an infinite loop!
[Spark DataFrame: find and set the main root for child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243425/spark-dataframe-find-and-set-the-main-root-for-child)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the "depth" of the hierarchy, you could use a `foldLeft` to aggregate a series of `self-join`s, as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  (123, 456), (145, 111), (456, 789), (789, 999), (787, 676)
).toDF("obj", "obj_parent")

val depth = 3

(1 to depth).foldLeft(df){ (accDF, _) =>
  accDF.as("df1").
    join(df.as("df2"), $"df1.obj_parent" === $"df2.obj", "left_outer").
    select($"df1.obj".as("obj"), coalesce($"df2.obj_parent", $"df1.obj_parent").as("obj_parent"))
}.show
// +---+----------+
// |obj|obj_parent|
// +---+----------+
// |123|       999|
// |145|       111|
// |456|       999|
// |789|       999|
// |787|       676|
// +---+----------+
```

Note that it'll work fine even if the provided value of "depth" is larger than the actual hierarchical depth, although in that case some of the trailing transformations would be redundant.

Comment: But we do not know the depth. In that case what we should do?

Comment: Maybe consider using [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html) which is reputedly a neat tool for [processing hierarchical data](https://www.qubole.com/blog/processing-hierarchical-data-using-spark-graphx-pregel-api/).